# Get Website content after delay in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, request

I need to load a website and search for a specific div id to get the content. The problem is: when the axios/http/whatever returns the response, the div is not there yet, because this div is appended into the html after some request.
I need not the "first" response, I need the response after some delay, like 3 seconds, because the div will be there.

```js
const getWebsiteContent = async (url) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(url)
    const $ = cheerio.load(response.data)
    // div is not here yet
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
}
```

Comment: Consider a callback function.  So put the above code inside a function and have it execute another function when finished e.g https://codeburst.io/javascript-what-the-heck-is-a-callback-aba4da2deced

Comment: You could also try .then() e.g `axios.get('http://www.somepage.com/${response.someValue}');
})
.then(function response { // Reponse being the result of the second request
    // Handle response
})
.catch(function (error) {
    // Handle error.
});` taken from https://medium.com/codebuddies/getting-to-know-asynchronous-javascript-callbacks-promises-and-async-await-17e0673281ee

Answer (score 1):

> the div is not there yet, because this div is appended into the html after some request

That means that it's being added via JavaScript or being loaded into a frame, which `axios` does not do (it's just reading the page source), it just reads the data from the URL. Waiting won't help, because it will never load.

Instead, you may want to determine where that data is actually being loaded from, and programmatically fetch that data with another request. Alternately, you could use a headless browser, but that has much more overhead.